# How would you pop an element from the end of a list in scala, and add it to the end of another list?

Tags: scala, list

I am currently working with two lists, and I wanted to know what was the best way to pop the last element from one list and add it to the end of another list in Scala? I can't find the pop equivalent of Python in Scala so I'm a little confused.

For example:

```
list1: List1[Int] = List(4,5,6)

list2: List2[Int] = List(5,7,8)
```

From there I want to add the last element of List 2 to List1, and return

```
list3: List1[Int] = List(4,5,6,8)

list4: List2[Int] = List(5,7)
```

Comment: A `List` is immutable. What you're asking is easy to do but the results are `list3` and `list4`, i.e. new lists. If you want to mutate existing collections you might try `Stack` which has `.push` and `.pop` or `Queue` which has `.enqueue` and `.dequeue`.

Comment: ah thank you, i'll look into queue's and such!

Comment: If you want to try an immutable and recursive alternative, `List` are meant to be constructed and traversed in a **head-tail** _fashion_, so you could be taking the head of one add prepending it to another, there is even the `reverse_:::` method which will do that: `List(3, 2, 1) reverse_:::List(4, 5, 6) === List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`.

Comment: No-one has yet pointed out that accessing the last element of a list is O(N) in the size of the list. So a different data structure is probably the way to go. Whether Stack and Queue are appropriate depends a little on how often you will need to do this  - is it just a one off or inside a key loop in your program etc.

Comment: its inside a loop, basically its inside a while loop and while the condition is true, i want it to take the last element from one list and remove it from that list, and then add it to another list. i've been looking at buffered lists so far and i think those might work but if you have any better implementations i'm happy to learn

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to compute `list4` using `init`, but `list3` needs care because `list2` might be empty. This is a safe way to do it:

```
list3 = list1 ++ list2.takeRight(1)
list4 = list2.init
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to manipulate the list, you can use `mutable` collections of Scala, which is highly not recommended. But just to give a flavour of it, this how you can do it:

```
  val list1 = mutable.ListBuffer(4,5,6)
  val list2 = mutable.ListBuffer(5,7,8)

  val dropped = list2.remove(list2.size - 1)

  println(list2)
  list1.append(dropped) // OR you can use => 
  // list1 += dropped
  println(list1)
```

---

**Update**: Here are few options for without making `List` `mutable`. Now you can either make new lists out of it like `newList1` and `newList2` or make them variable `var` .

> Disclaimer: having `var`s in your Scala code is a big NO, unless you
>   are really sure about why you are doing it.

Here is the sample (similar to the above) code for both approaches:

1. With `newList1` and `newList2`

> ```
>  val list1 = List(4,5,6)
>  val list2 = List(5,7,8)
>
>  val (newList2, dropped) = list2.splitAt(list2.size - 1)
>
>  val newList1 = list1 ++ dropped
>
>  println(newList2)
>  println(newList1)
> ```

2. With `var`s

> ```
> var list1 = List(4,5,6)
> var list2 = List(5,7,8)
>
> val result = list2.splitAt(list2.size - 1)
> val dropped = result._2
> list2 = result._1
> list1 = list1 ++ dropped
>
> println(list2)
> println(list1)
> ```

Comment: we don't need mutable list actually!!

Comment: The true solution lies in the true context, actually. Multiple approaches updated

Comment: true solution lies in the true context but using mutable unnecessary is going out of functional context

Answer (score 1):

If you can change you approach to use immutable list,
you can achieve it by

```
val list1 = List(4,5,6)
val list2 = List(5,7,8)
val list3 = list1 :+ list2.last
val list4 = list2.dropRight(1)
println(list3, list4)
```

output

```
(List(4, 5, 6, 8),List(5, 7))
```

Comment: This will fail if `list2` is empty

Comment: Right. Your answer is more suitable. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use mutable list you can do that by using simple operations like last and drop.

```
val list1 = List(4,5,6)

val list2= List(5,7,8)
```

what you can do is:

```
//val lastElem = list1.last // can cause an error if list is empty

can use takeRight instead

val lastElem = list1.takeRight(1)

print(list1 :+ lastElem, list2.drop(1)) // output, List(4,5,6,8), List(5, 7)
```

You can also save these values into new val

```
val appenedList = list1:+lastElem
val popedList = list2.drop(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `init`(which is opposite of `tail`) and `last` (which is opposite of `head`) method of scala `list`.

```
val list1 = List(1,2,3)
val list2 = List(4,5,6)

val newList1 = list1 ++ List(list2.last)   // return 1,2,3,6
val newList2 = list2.init   // return 4,5
```